# The texture atlas in Pixi.js is huge, so instead of moving the model page, a black rectangle is drawn. What is the reason?

Tags: pixi.js

I am using the latest version of Pixi.js (v7.2.4). I use texture atlases to play up my soul sheets. It is stated that the texture atlases in the Pixi.js documents are both faster and take up less space than json. However, the size of the texture atlas is very large. instead of playing the sprite sheet, only a black square is drawn. According to my research, this is because the sprite sheet is too large. Since the atlas is very long, I will only give a part of it.

Here is my texture atlas:

```
const atlas = {
    frames: {
        frame0: {
            frame: {
                x: 9,
                y: 9,
                w: 567,
                h: 556
            }
        },
        frame1: {
            frame: {
                x: 594,
                y: 9,
                w: 567,
                h: 556
            }
        },
        frame2: {
            frame: {
                x: 1179,
                y: 9,
                w: 567,
                h: 556
            }
        },
        frame3: {
            frame: {
                x: 1764,
                y: 9,
                w: 567,
                h: 556
            }
        },
        frame4: {
            frame: {
                x: 2349,
                y: 9,
                w: 567,
                h: 556
            }
        }
    },
    meta: {
        image: "./Assets/sprite.png",
        format: "RGBA8888",
        size: {
            w: 18720,
            h: 574
        },
        scale: 8
    },
    animations:{
        idle:["frame0","frame1","frame2","frame3","frame4","frame5","frame6","frame7","frame8","frame9"],
        jump:["frame10","frame11","frame12","frame13","frame14","frame15","frame16","frame17","frame18","frame19"],
        run:["frame20","frame21","frame22","frame23","frame24","frame25","frame26","frame27"],
        throw:["frame28","frame29","frame30","frame31"]
    }
}
```